# QGIS format for 'Execute SQL query' in modeler

Tags: qgis, sql

I need to run the equivalent of the following from MapInfo SQL in the QGIS Execute SQL tool within the modeler.

```
Select * from Road_Reserves, DSC_Roads where DSC_Roads.Control="Private" and Road_Reserves.obj Intersects DSC_Roads.obj into Private_Road_Parcels
Update Private_Road_Parcels Set Control = "Private" DropIndex Auto
Select * from Road_Reserves, DSC_Roads where DSC_Roads.Control="WWRC" and Road_Reserves.obj Intersects DSC_Roads.obj into WWRC_Road_Parcels
Update WWRC_Road_Parcels Set Control = "WWRC" DropIndex Auto
Select * from Road_Reserves, DSC_Roads where DSC_Roads.Control="DSC" and Road_Reserves.obj Intersects DSC_Roads.obj into DSC_Road_Parcels
Update DSC_Road_Parcels Set Control = "DSC" DropIndex Auto
Select * from Road_Reserves, DSC_Roads where DSC_Roads.Control="State" and Road_Reserves.obj Intersects DSC_Roads.obj into State_Road_Parcels
Update State_Road_Parcels Set Control = "State" DropIndex Auto
```

I have tried it as follows in the DB Manager first but can't work out the code changes required for QGIS.

```
Update "Road_Reserves" --also tried Select * 
FROM "DSC_Roads", "Road_Reserves"
WHERE "DSC_Roads"."Control"='Private' and ST_Intersects("DSC_Roads"."geometry","Road_Reserves"."geometry")
Set "Road_Reserves"."Control"='Private'
```

The error is

> Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS Update
> "Road_Reserves"  FROM "DSC_Roads", "Road_Reserves" WHERE
> "DSC_Roads"."Control"='Private' and
> ST_Intersects("DSC_Roads"."geometry","Road_Reserves"."geometry") Set
> "Road_Reserves"."Control"='Private': 1 - near "Update": syntax error

Comment: Quick look, your SQL query is wrong for PostgreSQL. You can't have a SELECT with a SET statements within the same query. SELECT is for read-only queries. If you want to update, use UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well but same issue. QGIS uses SQL Lite.

Comment: By the generated SQL the code expects SELECT, not UPDATE. However, updates seem to be possible https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html but probably with some other method than the one you used.

Comment: @user30184 I tried with Select as well but didn't work. The data is not in postgres just a flat file so the syntax would need to be SQL lite.

Comment: Sorry just added it to the example not in actual code. Updated example.